# Looping two different array at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, hash

I have to loop through two different arrays at same time. Let's say I have two arrays like this:

```
    a1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
    a2 = ["e","f","g","h"]
```

I want output like this:

```
    a,e
    b,f
    c,g
    d,h
```

I tried this program, but it is printing both arrays two times:

```
    a1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
    a2 = ["e","f","g","h"]
    a1.each do |a|
    a2.each do |b|
    puts a[0]
    puts b[0]
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through one array, and use the current index to get the element you want in the other array:

```
a1.each_with_index do |a, i|
    puts "#{a},#{a2[i]}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach would be to use [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip):

> **zip(arg, ...) → new_ary**
>   **zip(arg, ...) { |arr| block } → nil**
>
> Converts any arguments to arrays, then merges elements of `self` with corresponding elements from each argument.
>
> This generates a sequence of `ary.size` *n*-element arrays, where *n* is one more than the count of arguments.

So you could say:

```
a1.zip(a2) do |a, b|
  # do things with `a` and `b` in here. `a` will be an element of `a1` and
  # `b` will be the corresponding element of `a2`.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
a1 = *?a..?d
a2 = *?e..?h

a1.zip(a2).map { |e| puts e.join ?, }
```

### Output

```
a,e
b,f
c,g
d,h
```